# Как указать относительный путь из jar

Tags: java, windows, сборка

Есть программа, которой необходимо читать из `.txt` файла , который редактируется человеком или другими программами. И на этапе проектирования, то есть в самой идеи, эти файлы закидывались в папку с проектом и проблем нe было.

Но проект все же надо собрать, и собранный проект не видит относительный путь из jar. Как мне указать путь относительно jar'ника?

Comment: А где лежит `txt` внутри `jar` или рядом или где?

Comment: Функция чтения файла как ресурса JAR и как внешнего файла будут разными. Соответственно пути к файлами будут кардинально отличаться по форме записи. Уточните какой вам вариант нужен. Где должен находиться файл - в JAR или вне JAR пакета? В вашем вопросе понятно только, что было одно, но стало другое.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указывать пути к файлам относительно корня проекта. Например:

```
File file = new File("src/test/text.txt");
```